# Limiting the queryset displayed after the foreign key in the template - Django

Tags: django

I know how to return all objects by a foreign key in a Django template. But how to limit their number to the last 3? Is it possible?

**Example**

Models.html

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Template.html

```
{% for tag in person.tag_set.all %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

What is expected (only the last 3 objects)?

```
{% for tag in person.tag_set.all[:3] %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you mean last three or first three? The slice in your question would return the first 3

Comment: What would it look like for the first 3 and the last 3? I think that would be a very useful answer.

Comment: Getting the first three is simple, you use the `slice` template filter like the answer below. Getting the last three is complicated since you can't really negatively slice a queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter to slice a queryset/list, this gets the first 3 items

```
{% for tag in person.tag_set.all|slice:":3" %}
```

[Negative indexing of querysets is not supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets), getting the last three would be complex in a template

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it possible to use in template, but you can prepare your queryset using reverse(). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#reverse